# How I could evaluate this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x^2+x+1} \,dx$$
I’ve tried so far integration by parts and partial fraction, each method has led to a dead end. So how I should evaluate this using standard methods, if is possible of course.

Comment: Aren't you able to establish a relationship between $I_n$ and $I_{n-1}$?

Comment: @pluton how I could do that?

Comment: Or $I_n$ and $I_{n-3}$

Comment: via an integration by parts actually...

Comment: $$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x^2+x+1} \,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n(1-x)}{1-x^3} \,dx=\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)\sum_{k\geq0}x^{3k} \,dx =\sum_{k\geq0}\int_0^1 x^{n+3k} - x^{n+3k+1} \,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach. I'm just going to sketch it out. First note that
$$\frac{x^{3n} - 1}{x^2+x+1} = (1 + x^3 + x^6 + \ldots + x^{3n-3})(x-1)$$
This formula allows you to evaluate $I_{3n},I_{3n+1},I_{3n+2}$ separately (by multiplying the above by $1$, $x$ and $x^2$) as a sum of $I_0,I_1,I_2$ respectively and the integral of polynomials (which will be rational).

For the polynomials above we can find a simple recursion for the integrals. For example for $I_{3n+1}$ we have
$$I_{3n+1} = I_1 + \int_0^1 \frac{x^{3n+1}-x}{x^2+x+1}{\rm d}x = I_1 + \int_0^1 P_n(x){\rm d}x$$

where the polynomial is

$$P_n(x) = x(1 + x^3 + x^6 + \ldots + x^{3n-3})(x-1)$$ 
which satisfy $P_{n+1}(x) = P_n(x)  + x(x-1)x^{3n}$ which is easy to integrate.

The integral $I_0$ can be solved by completing the square in the denominator and remembering $\int\frac{{\rm d}x}{1+x^2} = \arctan(x) + C$ (gives rise to $\pi$'s). For $I_1$ we can use a substitution $u = x^2+x+1$ (gives rise to $\log$'s) plus the result for $I_0$ and for $I_2$ we can use polynomial division and then the result for $I_1$ and $I_0$ (gives rise to $\pi$'s and $\log$'s).

This will lead to something like $I_{3n} = \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} + a_n$, $I_{3n+1} =  -\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\log(3)}{2} + b_n$ and $I_{3n+2} = 1-\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}} - \frac{\log(3)}{2} + c_n$ where $a_n,b_n,c_n$ are rational numbers which has simple recursion relations and will for $I_n$ correspond to a sum of $[n/3]$ terms (you will find an expression on the form  $-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2) + (9+6i) k + 9k^2}$ with $a_n$ corresponding to $i=0$, $b_n$ to $i=1$ and $c_n$ to $i=2$).

Comment: I got  what’s your point, but how to evaluate $I_n$?

Comment: @benj2k1 That is the whole point of the answer... If you know $I_{3k+i}$ for $i=0,1,2$ and integer $k$ then you know how to evaluate $I_n$ for any $n$. The answer doesn't have to be "one formula" for $I_n$. I did it this way as you will get an answer that is as simple as possible without invoking special non-elementary functions like the poly-gamma functions or hypergeometrical functions or having the answer as an infinite series. This gives you $I_n$ as a sum of an irrational number and a finite sum of rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Nosrati's comment
$$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x^2+x+1} \,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1 (x^{n+3k} - x^{n+3k+1}) \,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3 k+n+1) (3 k+n+2)}$$ gives
$$I_n=\frac{1}{3} \left(\psi \left(\frac{n+2}{3}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)\right)$$ where appears the digamma function.

Considering that $n$ can be large, using for each term the asymptotics
$$\psi(p)=\log \left({p}\right)-\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12 p^2}+\frac{1}{120
   p^4}-\frac{1}{252 p^6}+\frac{1}{240 p^8}-\frac{1}{132
   p^{10}}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^{12}}\right) $$ and continuing with Taylor expansions, we should get,as an *approximation*,
$$I_n=\frac{1}{3 n}\left(1-\frac{2}{3 n^2}+\frac{2}{n^4}-\frac{14}{n^6}+\frac{1618}{9
   n^8}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{10}}\right)\right)$$ which seems to be quite good for $n > 3$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 3 & 0.1065349 & 0.1045998 \\
 4 & 0.0804559 & 0.0803396 \\
 5 & 0.0650732 & 0.0650606 \\
 6 & 0.0546018 & 0.0545998 \\
 7 & 0.0470067 & 0.0470063 \\
 8 & 0.0412512 & 0.0412511 \\
 9 & 0.0367427 & 0.0367427 \\
 10 & 0.0331174 & 0.0331174
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I_{n} & \equiv \int_{0}^{1}{x^{n} \over x^{2} + x + 1}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n} - x^{n + 1}\over 1 - x^{3}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n/3 - 2/3} - x^{n/3 - 1/3} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n/3 - 1/3} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x - \int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n/3 - 2/3} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\bracks{\Psi\pars{{n \over 3} + {2 \over 3}} -
\Psi\pars{{n \over 3} + {1 \over 3}}}\qquad
\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\end{align}

> See
>   [$\mathbf{\color{black}{6.3.22}}$ in A&S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm).